# Passing data between states in the Ember.js state manager

Tags: ember.js

I have the following StateManager:

```
Lead.StateManager = Ember.StateManager.extend
  initialState: 'notParsing'

  notParsing: Ember.State.create
    startParsing: (manager, search) ->
      manager.goToState 'parsing'

  parsing: Ember.State.create
    enter: ->
```

I am able to transition from the notParsing state to the parsing state by using the send method of the stateManager like this:

```
@state_manager.send('startParsing', {search_url: "http://thesoftwaresimpleton.com/"})
```

I can pass arguments via the send message but I cannot pass arguments using goToState because it only accepts a name argument.

Can anybody point out how I can pass the argument that is passed into startParsing action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if my solution is a good one and it surely depends on the use case, but you could store properties on the `manager` itself, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/6Q39q/.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.StateManager = Ember.StateManager.extend({
    initialState: 'notParsing',

    notParsing: Ember.State.create({
        startParsing: function(manager, search) {
            manager.set('url', search.searchUrl);
            manager.goToState('parsing');
        }
    }),
    parsing: Ember.State.create({
        enter: function(manager) {
            this._super();
            var url = manager.get('url');
            console.log('start parsing url: %@'.fmt(url));
        }
    })
});

var stateManager = App.StateManager.create();
stateManager.send('startParsing', {
    searchUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
});​
```

Another solution would be to use controllers, which are set on the `stateManager` instance, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Y9KyA/.

Comment: In the sproutcore statechart, it is possible to pass arguments with gotoState.  I wonder why it is not possible with Ember?

Maybe I should use an observerable for this.